# Show Window Previews in Dock

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dash-to-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am aware of the option to show window previews in Dash-to-dock when e.g. middle clicking an application (and a similar option in Dash-to-panel).

Using the python IDE, opening multiple windows looks like this on the dock (see right side):

[image]

Each window is also titled 'Toplevel' which does nothing in helping me differentiate between the windows. As such, I'm looking for some sort of workaround (or gnome extension) that puts the window previews in the dock itself, without me having to middle click them (just for ease of use reasons).

Comment: Possible now in the newer Dash-to-Dock extension. That can probably be installed in 18.04 as well.

Comment: @vanadium Could you point me to where I can get the new extension?

Comment: In the usual way: Gnome Shell extensions website.

Comment: @vanadium I've installed it but I'm not seeing any difference? I've enabled the "Show previews of open windows" option but I'm not seeing any previews in the dock.

Comment: Not sure, I am not using it myself.